# Too Many Connection with ActiveRecord and Server-Sent Events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, server-sent-events, puma

I use SSE for something like "instant messaging" in my rails app. I have a problem when I have more connections than my pool database value.

What's the solution to allow more users without this "pool" limit?

I use something similar to http://rubysnippets.com/2013/04/10/rails-4-live-streaming-versus-node-dot-js/

My server is Puma and I use Redis and `ActionController::Live`.

Comment: Configure your database to accept more connections.

Comment: Is it possible to use something like 500 connections with Puma on Heroku ?

Comment: No, it isn't. If you're on heroku, you need to either pay for a better database inside heroku, setup your database out of heroku or just don't use Rails for this.

Comment: Also, needing 500 connections is surely a bad sign, your app shouldn't have to open this many connections.

Comment: It seems each connection to the "instant message page" need a connection. I use somthing similar to http://rubysnippets.com/2013/04/10/rails-4-live-streaming-versus-node-dot-js/

I use Puma and Redis

Comment: I think the problem is with ActionController::Live

Comment: WOW. Well, Rails is definitely a really bad choice for this. You should definitely try something else like Goliath/EventMachine or go for a different environment like Scala, Go or NodeJS.

Comment: i've a messages system, but i want make it "live" when peoples are connected. So, i've rails models for the users, the messages. I'm a little bit lost about the environment to use... Goliath ? EventMachine ? NodeJS ? What's your opinion ?